# Kotlin fragment send bundle data to other fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have following code which is sending `a` data to next fragment and it's working just fine, the problem is that I need to send second bundle data and I don't know how?

`working`

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v!!.id) {
            R.id.orderst_detail -> {
                navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_backToOrderFragment_to_mapToCustomerFragment)
            }
            R.id.maptoLaundry -> {
                val bundle = bundleOf("laundryAddressArgument" to laundry_address_text2.text.toString())
                navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_laundryAddressFragment_to_mapToLaundryFragment, bundle)
            }
        }
    }
```

`not working`

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v!!.id) {
            R.id.orderst_detail -> {
                navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_backToOrderFragment_to_mapToCustomerFragment)
            }
            R.id.maptoLaundry -> {
                val bundle = bundleOf("laundryAddressArgument" to laundry_address_text2.text.toString())
                val bundle2 = bundleOf("orderIDArgument" to orderIDArgument)
                navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_laundryAddressFragment_to_mapToLaundryFragment, bundle,bundle2)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note**

In second code I'm trying to send `val bundle2 = bundleOf("orderIDArgument" to orderIDArgument)` in addition to `val bundle = bundleOf("laundryAddressArgument" to laundry_address_text2.text.toString())`

**Any idea?**

Comment: We can use same bundle to put data. 
val bundle = bundleOf("laundryAddressArgument" to "xyc")
bundle.putString("orderIDArgument" , "id value")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the same bundle to put data.

```
val bundle = bundleOf("laundryAddressArgument" to "xyc") 
bundle.putString("orderIDArgument" , "id value")

navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_laundryAddressFragment_to_mapToLaundryFragment, bundle)
```

Comment: Thank you, please wait 5 min, still can't accept it by rules

Comment: sure, no worries..@mafortis

Answer (score 0):

`Bundle` is a data container, you can wrap all the data you want to send inside `Bundle` and pass the bundle, no need to create multiple bundles

```
val bundle = bundleOf("laundryAddressArgument" to laundry_address_text2.text.toString(), 
                      "orderIDArgument" to orderIDArgument)
navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_laundryAddressFragment_to_mapToLaundryFragment, bundle)
```